# OpenCV: Issues in using color frames with SURF features

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, tracking, detection, surf

I am trying to work with this code so that SURF can be implemented using color frames/images and then use the code here [Kalman_Color_Object_Track](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_Motion_Tracking.htm)to track the detected object using the color value by Kalman filter. So, these are the steps that I intend to do but I am stuck since this SURF detection code does not accept/work with color images:

1. "book1.png" is the color image
2. After the rectangle around the image is detected from the incoming frames, the Mat structure is changed to IplImage since the Kalman_Color_Object_Track code is in C++ by

   dest_image=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)image);

   mat_frame=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)frame);
3. Call the `Kalman_Color_Object_Track( mat_frame,dest_image,30);` method.

**Questions** : (A) How to make this code work so that SURF features can be extracted and detected for color images? (B) I am unsure what should be passed in the function signature of `Kalman_Color_Object_Track()` and (C) where exactly in the object detection module should it be called?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <iostream>
     #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

    using namespace cv;
    IplImage *mat_dest_image=0;
    IplImage *mat_frame=0;
/* Object Detection and recognition from video*/



   int main()
    {
       Mat object = imread( "book1.png", );

        if( !object.data )
        {
            std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        int minHessian = 500;

        SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
        std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

        detector.detect( object, kp_object );

        //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
        SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
        Mat des_object;

        extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );

        FlannBasedMatcher matcher;



        namedWindow("Good Matches");
    namedWindow("Tracking");

        std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

        //Get the corners from the object
        obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
        obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
        obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
        obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

        char key = 'a';
        int framecount = 0;
           VideoCapture cap("booksvideo.avi");

           for(; ;)

       {
           Mat frame;
            cap >> frame;
            imshow("Good Matches", frame);


            Mat des_image, img_matches;
            std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
            std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
            std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
            std::vector<Point2f> obj;
            std::vector<Point2f> scene;
            std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
            Mat H;
            Mat image;

            //cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

            detector.detect( image, kp_image );
            extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );

            matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

            for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS  LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
            {
                if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
                {
                    good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
                }
            }

            //Draw only "good" matches
            drawMatches( object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

            if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
                {
                    //Get the keypoints from the good matches
                    obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
                    scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
                }

                H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

                perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

                //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
                line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
                line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
                line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
                line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    mat_dest_image=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)image);
    mat_frame=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)frame);

    Kalman_Color_Object_Track( ); // The tracking method
            }

            //Show detected matches
            imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
            for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
    { printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i,    good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); }
            waitKey(0);

       }
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://www.science.uva.nl/research/publications/2010/vandeSandeTPAMI2010/vandeSandeTPAMI2010-EvaluatingColorDescriptors.pdf) implemented the SIFT descriptor on color images by computing gradient histograms for each channel independently. Perhaps you could try the same approach for SURF features.

Comment: Thank you for the link. So, it is not possible to tweak the above code for color counterpart? I was hoping if something can be done to the code. And, if without working with color properties, how and where should I plug in the call to the kalman filter?

Comment: If you split the image into channels and compute 3 sets of descriptors, one for each channel, and do matching on each set you might get something useful.

Comment: Ok. Can you put the code for splitting into each channel? Also, where should the call to tracking module be placed?Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the function cvSplit.